# Loop condition hasNext(), hasNextLine(), hasNextInt() and End of File

Tags: java

I have to write a programme that takes in a word, and 2 integers. The programme should stop when it reaches End Of File.

The following is my initial code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str;
    int x, y;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {

      str = scan.next();
      x = scan.nextInt();
      y = scan.nextInt();
   }
 }
}
```

But I got an error. I change the while condition to `scan.hasNextLine()`, and it still didn't work. Eventually, I change the condition to `scan.hasNext()`, and it worked. Why?

Comment: Do I have an `int`? Yes? Great, give me a `String` **and** 2 `int`(s). But you only checked for **one** `int`.

Comment: If you wanna use `scan.hasNextLine()` tou need to read a line in every loop then parse it to String and two `int`, otherwise you need to check for the availability of the next token then read it. But `hasNextInt()` is checking for the existence of the next int without checking for the next String.

Comment: `hasNextInt`, `hasNextLine` and `hasNext` are really self-explanatory method names that only requires that you think logically about what you want your code to do. The only counter-intuitive issue you might run into is with next-line and new-line characters at the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()) of `Scanner` you will find:

> `public boolean hasNext()`
>
> Returns true if this scanner has another
> **token** in its input.

If you want to use `hasNextLine()`, you need to read a *line* in every loop then *parse* it to a `String` and *two* `int`s, otherwise you need to check for the availability of the *next token* then read it. In which a token can be an `int` or a `String` in your case via using the above-mentioned `public boolean hasNext()` method.

On the other hand, `hasNextInt()` is checking for the existence of the next `int` ***without*** checking for the next `String`, thus the condition logic in your `while-loop` is not appropriate in your program.